# Is there any better way to write my Laravel Routes by avoiding namespace repeaters

Tags: php, laravel

I try to clean my code **api.php** in **Laravel 9.**

I'm not sure if there is a better way to avoid repeating controller namespace.
Here is my code:

```
Route::controller(App\Http\Controllers\Contacts\ContactController::class)->prefix('contacts')->group(function(){
        Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\Contacts\ContactController::class, 'index']);
    });
```

**Note** : I want to groupe by Controller

Comment: you wouldn't be passing the 'callable' as the second argument to `Route::get` inside that `controller` group, it would just be the method, so that would remove the repeating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're half way there. `Route::controller` permits you to write your routes in the group like this:

```
Route::get('/', 'index');
```

i.e.

```
Route::controller(App\Http\Controllers\Contacts\ContactController::class)->prefix('contacts')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/', 'index');
});
```

This will result in the `index` function of the group's controller being called.